# Use Graphics on LogLog axis

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can one overlay graphics objects (like Rectangles) on Log-Log axes?

Thanks

Comment: I think linked topics should fit your needs but let me know if I missed the point or you don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListLogLogPlot[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 6],
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[]}],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]